# Running a dedicated security network

Tags: networking, router, ip-camera

I'm trying to move my four bandwidth hungry IP cameras over to their own personal network. I need software that monitors them 24/7 for motion and that slows down my main router. If I were to get another router, how would I bridge the two so that the second router does the heavy lifting routing the traffic between the IP Cameras and the motion detector but can still send and receive from the internet (WAN).

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about how they all connect ?

With the little information you have provided it sounds like all you need to do is put the cameras, motion sensor on the switch and then cable that switch into the router.   This seems similar to a problem I've had before where the router was pretending to be a 4 port switch, but was actually 4 ports bridged together with software, and not able to cope with the load.  Using a proper (but cheap) 8 port switch fixed the problem.

If the cameras and motion detectors are all in the same subnet (typically indicated if the first 3 octets of the IP address are the same), then this will most likely solve your problem as there is actually no routing going on - simply switching.

Comment: These cameras are over wifi, which is why a router is my choice. Does this change anything?

Comment: In that case - and this is probably not what you want to heare -  ditch the WIFI and replace it with physical cables. You are probably eathing your limited bandwidth on WIFI, and thats the problem.  You may be able to set up a second Access Point on a different channel and use that and it could improve things, however that is a bad solution as it wastes bandwidth - and depending on how congested WIFI is in your area might not work that well.  (note that the solution using an Access Point is similar to using a switch - an access point is the wireless equivalent of a switch)